# C# - How to get DNS TTL?

Tags: c#, .net, dns

I am not seeing a direct way to read DNS records (A and CNAME records). I am mostly interested in getting the TTL for entries.

Can this somehow be missing in the .net framework?

Comment: There's a nuget package called Dnsclient that can retrieve various kinds of DNS records. https://www.nuget.org/packages/DnsClient/

Comment: If you use the OS default resolution functions, like `getaddrinfo` the TTL is not returned because it is tied to the DNS where name resolution can happen in different ways (`/etc/hosts` file, LDAP, etc.) where the concept of TTL does not exist. Newer APIs like `getdns` may give you this information (and the relevant wrapper around it in your language). Otherwise if you do DNS queries yourself through any relevant libraries, you will then obviously also have this data.